# Is it possible to make the options menu come from the side, instead of the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a game where, when the game is being played, the phone will be in landscape mode, but when the menu button is pressed, I want the options menu to come from the right side instead of the bottom of the screen. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this, at least no with the normal menu system. Its not the expected result from the users perspective and will considered an interface design issue.

That said if you lock the phone to portrait mode the buttons will be on the side, although sideways. This would also require you to modify your drawing code, so don't do it.

Instead you should just catch the menu key press and make your own menu system, much simpler and you'll have complete control for your game.